# To customize styles for RWD theme regarding IE-7 browser compatibility view

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, rwd-theme

I need to style for **front-end** regarding **Internet Explorer 7** Browser compatibility view. I've been implemented my custom theme for our site from **RWD theme**. Now i'm using magento version of  **1.9.1.0**. While i tried to design for **ie-8**, I chose **ie-8.css** stylesheet which was in the directory. In page.xml it simply itself assigned for IE browsers verison **lte IE-8**. While i checked styles in IE-8 browser, it worked as charm. But when switching to **IE-7** by using **IE developer's mode**, Total design getting crashed. I don't know what i did mistake in it. Can any one give suggestions regarding this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which version of IE you are using. While in developer mode in IE you can select both what version of IE to use and what 'docs mode' version to use.  So you could be testing this with IE7 browser version and IE9 docs mode which could cause issues and isn't really an environment you would most likely need to code for.

If you need to code around users possibly using older versions of IE with compatibility mode enabled try editing app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/page/html/head.phtml with this meta tag in order to try to force the browser out of compatibility mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Be sure that this is the very first meta tag and is above any IE conditional statements.

You may need to clear all Magento caches after these changes before testing them.